# Unlock Windows programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

In my current C# code I'm able to lock a Windows user session programmatically (same as Windows + L).

Since the app would still be running, is there any way to unlock the session from that C# program. User credentials are known. The app is running on Windows 7.

Comment: If you have the credentials (username and password) you have another problem.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764174/unlock-local-computer-using-net

Comment: My recommendation is not to lock the workstation. I mean, if you want it unlocked then just refrain from locking it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain why you want the session to be unlocked automatically? What's the use case?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a custom windows credential provider to log in for you. Also, you'll need to save the user's credentials somewhere to log in. There are some samples in Windows SDK 7 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

There's a bunch of projects to get you started under `Samples\security\credentialproviders`.

To unlock the screen:

- set the username / password in `CSampleCredential::Initialize`
- set autologin to true in `CSampleCredential::SetSelected`
- search the hardware provider sample for `WM_TOGGLE_CONNECTED_STATUS` message to see how to trigger the login
- build some way to communicate with your app to trigger the unlock (local tcp server for example)

It's a pain in the ass, but it works.

Comment: I'd like to get this solution working on Windows 10 but my Windows skills are rusty. Please contact me through the site on my profile page if you'd be interested in doing some consulting work here.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some hackery to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16197/Remotely-Unlock-a-Windows-Workstation
Didn't test it myself though.

Not for .NET part, but you could also make your own custom Logon UI and inject some mechanism there. It can easily become security problem though.

Answer (score -2):

```
    var path = new ManagementPath();
    path.NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption"; path.ClassName = "Win32_EncryptableVolume";

    var scope = new ManagementScope(path, new ConnectionOptions() { Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate });

    var management = new ManagementClass(scope, path, new ObjectGetOptions());

    foreach (ManagementObject vol in management.GetInstances())
    {

        Console.WriteLine("----" + vol["DriveLetter"]);
        switch ((uint)vol["ProtectionStatus"])
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("not protected by bitlocker");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("unlocked");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("locked");
                break;
        }

        if ((uint)vol["ProtectionStatus"] == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unlock this driver ...");

            vol.InvokeMethod("UnlockWithPassphrase", new object[] { "here your pwd" });

            Console.WriteLine("unlock done.");
        }
    }
```

Note: this only works if you run Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: getting invalid namespace at runtime on the foreach line even though I am using System.Management.

Comment: The question is about to unlock windows not about unlocking bitlocker locked drives

Answer (score -13):

No, there is no way to do this, by design. What's your scenario and why do you need to lock/unlock the workstation?

Comment: It can be done on Vista and windows 7 defiantly. Look at logmein and face recognition logins; I don't know how to do it though

Comment: @Will03uk: Those are done by writing a custom GINA DLL (which controls the login authentication process).

Comment: I've just looked it up and since Vista the GINA DLL has been replaced with Credential Providers which allows more flexibility and more then one provider a time

Comment: That's not true. You can use a custom Credential provider.

Answer (score -14):

Of course you can't unlock it.  Unlocking a session requires the user physically be there to enter their account credentials.  Allowing software to do this, even with saved credentials, would be a security issue for many of the other situations where workstation locking is used.

Comment: Which is also why you need to use ctrl+alt+del

Comment: -1 granted, it is a security issue but as proven by logmein, possible

Comment: That's not true. You can use a custom Credential provider.