# Unlock Windows 10 Programmatically

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10, windows-security

I'm building an app to auto unlock/lock a workstation based on proximity to a mobile app.  The solution would be similar to the Microsoft app described [here](https://betanews.com/2016/01/14/microsoft-will-let-your-unlock-your-windows-10-pc-with-an-app/), so I'm pretty sure it's possible.

**What API can I use to programmatically unlock a Windows 10 workstation?**  I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975206/unlock-windows-programmatically), but it is six years old, and I don't know if the techniques it describes are even valid for Windows 10.

Because this app will rely on Bluetooth LE, it requires Windows 10+, so I don't need a solution that supports older OS versions.

I'm a seasoned programmer but haven't done any Windows programming in 10 years, so I'm not sure where to look.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the linked answer talking about credential providers is the way to go, it's still valid for Windows 10.  There is [another API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/companion-device-unlock) that the app you linked to probably uses, but its pre-approval for 3rd parties.