# doesnt work keyboard in login screen with pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

I'm running the following code on the windows login screen, but the password doesn't write, how can I do? or how can I enter a password

```
import win32api
#running this code in windows login screen
time.sleep(10)
#password
win32api.keybd_event(55, 0, 0, 0) 
win32api.keybd_event(55, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(55, 0, 0, 0)
#password
win32api.keybd_event(13, 0, 0, 0) #enter
```

Comment: No one to help ? :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set your program to run as a server, because once you log off the windows, your program will end. Second, `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` should be added after each key has been pressed:
`win32api.keybd_event(55, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);`

However, this method of automatic login is not very cool. You could use the tool--[Autologon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)

Anther way:set the registry, under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`, set as below,

```
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"            //enable Auto Logon
"DefaultUserName"="User"        //set the User Name
"DefaultDomainName"="Domain"    //set the Domain Name
"DefaultPassword"="Password"    //set the Password
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to do this, I'm trying to open the computer that is locked with the web service (non-sleep computer) but I'm not typing the password with win32api when the computer is locked and the enter doesn't work.

I'm running the code above and locking the windows, the program is running behind, waiting for windows to open with 10 seconds after 777 + enter,
i making robot 

Comment: You'll need a custom windows credential provider to log in for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975206/unlock-windows-programmatically

Comment: thank you drake wu , i think i should work more a bit :)