# Unlocking computer with NFC-enabled phone

Tags: windows, macos, authentication, applescript, nfc

I want to have an NFC sticker on my laptop/desktop which when swiped with my NFC phone will unlock my computer. If I don't have my phone with me, I can still login using my normal password. I so far bought some NFC stickers and installed [TagStand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) on my phone which manages to post to a server that I control. I want to write some small piece of software that would listen to this server and unlock my computer if the server tells my computer to do so. I have not made the last part work as I don't know how to write such a software for either Mac or PC. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: You might start with the code for an existing app like BTproximity and replace the trigger code to use your NFC messages instead.

Comment: Windows supports logging on using smart card + pin authentication.  If you have a NFC reader attached to your PC then you should be able to set up an android phone to behave like a smart card and then use this to better secure your PC - see http://randomoracle.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-smartcard-logon-with-android-secure-element-and-nfc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NFC part is very simple but the unlocking part is more complicated than you think. Unlocking your computer *should* **never** be done programmatically because if your program can do it, **then so can others.** Not to mention that this 'program' is going to act based on communication between a remote server and itself. This is a **security nightmare**, that has no use other than the experimental benefit.

If you do enough research you'll find that locking (not unlocking) a computer is possible programmatically. Unlocking on the other hand is not easy..

Here are a few links for you, I've been though them before, never tested them though...

[Remotely-Unlock-a-Windows-Workstation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16197/Remotely-Unlock-a-Windows-Workstation)

[unlock-local-computer-using-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764174/unlock-local-computer-using-net)

[unlock-windows-workstation-programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174225/unlock-windows-workstation-programatically)

[aucun](http://www.paralint.com/projects/aucun/)

Comment: If it is so insecure, why are there keyfobs?

Comment: What you are saying is true, it is hard, and even harder to do so without "opening" any "backdoor" accidentally. I searched for this on google by curiosity, because me and some friends did an Android/Windows application to do exactly this, as for now it is working properly, we are still working on ours "handshake" which is not as secure as we would like it to be as of right now, our project is GPLv2 and we have a github, once we finish our secure handshake protocol we've been working on, I'll share our github with you guys, if you have questions feel free to message me!

Answer (score 0):

I thing another way of accomplishing this would be to do it the other way around. Have your phone store your password in an app that could pass it along to the computer. The computer would need some sort of USB NFC reader that would essentially act as a keyboard. When you tap your phone to the USB device it "types" your password into the text box and the last thing the app does is "hit the enter key" Obvious security issue is if you are running the unlocker app it is essentially just constantly sending out your password...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to note that Asus has launched a product that does this (allows NFC login) for windows 8, so it is possible - as far as how secure it is I don't know...